# declaring the underlying type of enumeration identifier

Tags: c++, types, enums, enum-class

I have declared an enum as follows:

```
enum fileType {typeA, typeB};
```

This is causing an error when I try to append directoryType type to a string.
I believe I need to include the underlying type of the enumeration identifiers in the enum declaration. Or something like

```
enum fileType : string {typeA, typeB};
```

as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e(v=vs.80).aspx

however this is not compiling for me. What is the proper syntax for declaring the underlying type of enum identifiers?

Comment: In your link `This can be any scalar type, such as signed or unsigned versions of int, short, or long. bool or char is also allowed.` You cannot use `String` or whatever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have only integral types as underlying type for enum. That means signed and unsigned types like `char` `short` `int` and `long`.

The names of enumerations are nowhere available runtime. If you want to display them (or append to string) then you have to write special code.

```
 enum fileType {typeA, typeB};
 const char *fileType_str[]={ "typeA","typeB"};

 fileType x = typeA;
 // display x
 std::cout << "x is " << fileType_str[x] << std::endl;

 // append x to string
 std::string y = "directoryType type to a ";
 y += fileType_str[x];
```